# How do facial recognition programs work?

Tags: computer-vision, face-recognition

What flow would the program go through?

Comment: your question is off topic - it might be suited at cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Daniel A. White: According to the FAQ, questions about software algorithms and programming problems are on-topic on SO. Face recognition is a programming problem that's solved using software algorithms. I don't see how this is off-topic.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Very roughly, the processing stages would be:

1. Detect face positions
2. Normalize the faces
3. Collect features for each detected face
4. Feed the features to a machine learning algorithm

Step 1 is usually done using the classic [Viola&Jones face detection algorithm](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf). It's quite fast and reliable.

The faces found in step 1 may have different brightness, contrast and different sizes. To simplify processing, they are all scaled to the same size and exposure differences are compensated (e.g. using histogram equalization) in step 2.

There are many approaches to step 3. Early face detectors tried to find specific positions (center of the eyes, end of the nose, end of the lips, etc.) and use geometric distances and angles between those as features for recognition. From what I've read, these approaches were very fast, but not that reliable.

A more recent approach, "Eigenfaces", is based on the fact that pictures of faces can be approximated as a linear combination of base images (found through PCA from a large set of training images). The linear factors in this approximation can be used as features. This approach can also be applied to parts of the face (eyes, nose, mouth) individually. It works best if there the pose between all images is the same. If some faces look to the left, others look upwards, it won't work as well. Active appearance models try to counter that effect by training a full 3d model instead of flat 2d pictures.

Step 4 is relatively straightforward: You have a set of numbers for each face, and for the face images acquired during training, and you want to find the training face that's "most similar" to the current test face. That's what machine learning algorithms do. I think the most common algorithm is the support vector machine (SVM). Other choices are e.g. artificial neural networks or k-nearest neighbors. If the features are good, the choice of the ML algorithm won't matter that much.

Literature on the subject:

- [Computer Vision - Algorithms an Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848829345) treats face detection, face recognition and machine learning (among many other subjects). It's quite new so it covers the latest research. It also has a great bibliography.
- [Template Matching Techniques in Computer Vision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470517069) treats template matching approaches to face recognition, in depth.
- And you can find lots of research articles using google scholar.

Answer (score 3):

[Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_Component_Analysis) is at the base of pattern recognition systems such as [facial recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_recognition_system).

Comment: I would say rather that principal components analysis is one technique use in face recognition.  Although PCA is useful, not all face recognition solutions use PCA.