# Face Recognisation IOS

Tags: ios, face-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I perform facial recogntion on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020842/how-can-i-perform-facial-recogntion-on-ios)

We were working on Face Detection algorithm where we want to not only detect Face Smile and Eyes, we also want to compare the same with other photos smile and Eye, and out of those we want find best smile and eye photo.

So currently we were able to detect the the Smile and Eye but we are not able to find solution to compare the same?

Did anybody had tried the same before?

Comment: What makes a smile and eye "best"?

Comment: See also [How do facial recognition programs work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978630/how-do-facial-recognition-programs-work)

Comment: Eyes will be at its Best when they are fully open (so we would be able to detect when it is closed) and same case with Smile.